# How can we get Location coordinates in android without internet?

Tags: android, geolocation

How can we get Location coordinates in android without internet? By Using internet I am getting coordinates from Network.But when I am offline its returns Last Known Location ?

Comment: Without GPS & Internet Can we get location co-ordinates?Because in Indoor areas GPS not worked properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By Using internet I am getting coordinates from Network

Change your provider to `GPS_PROVIDER` , instead of `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Comment: @user3471594 did you try the solution ?

Comment: Without GPS & Internet Can we get location co-ordinates?Because in Indoor areas GPS not worked properly.

Comment: Inside the room, GPS_PROVIDER may not work but NETWORK_PROVIDER will always work as long as you have coverage in your mobile.

Comment: Since you are new to the StackOverflow let me guide you, how to accept a useful answer. If my answer is best useful for your question then tick the green tick mark besides my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Location by using GPS that doesn't require internet
You have to change your provider from LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER to LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;